# In data science, what is the difference between using x X?

Tags: python, data-science

In data science, what is the difference between using x X?
But y is all lowercase.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
reg.score(X, y)

reg.coef_

reg.intercept_

reg.predict(np.array([[3, 5]]))
```

Comment: It just variable name

Comment: Usually a capital variable name is used for matrices, and a lower case variable is used for vectors. Sklearn uses this convention. I.e. it is just a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It a representation depends on one's preference.*
But we generally use 'X' instead of 'x' bcz of mathematical representation of matrix using uppercase letter. And here **X** represents the **features matrix**.
The features matrix is assumed to be two-dimensional, with shape [n_samples, n_features].
And y is represented as **target array** i.e assumed to be one-dimensional.
feel free to check this out:
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.02-introducing-scikit-learn.html
you will get a clear idea.